# Database warehouse design for reporting and analytical tools

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, data-warehouse, olap

I am new to OLAP database design, I have a mysql database with the following tables:-

```
countries(id, name);
occupations(id, name);
areas(id, name);
purposes(id, name);
tickets(id, issue_date, country_id, occupation_id, area_id, purpose_id, first_name, last_name, gender, birth_date, cost, quantity, .....);
```

This is a simplified version of my transactional database, which is updated regularly on every sales. If my tickets table is populated with around 1000 rows every day. How do I design my olap/database so that, I can view the data daily, weekly, monthly an yearly on the chart?

I can portray the data on the chart using the above table for daily, but for weekly, monthly and so on due to the large sets of data, the application gets unresponsive!

**UPDATE!**
The database schema itself is acting as a star schema in my opinion, with a fact table as tickets and other dimensional table as countries, occupations, areas, etc. Do I really need another schema? May be I don't even required it at all. Only my concern is, when the tickets table is asked to get all data of from a year, it will fetch around 1000*365 records or more! Is it normal?

Comment: 1000 records a day isn't very many. But where is the date of the sale in your tickets table that you're querying on? What is the issue you're seeing, that you're getting too many rows back, or that when you get the one row back for a year, it takes a long while to get? I agree this is almost like a star schema, so the missing piece is a date table with one row per day. In that table you'd have many columns representing the month, year etc. You'd use this to filter on years or months.

Answer (score -1):

OLTP & OLAP models have different requirements (you may Google about that for more details) so using the OLTP model for OLAP analysis might not be the right solution especially when the amount of data starts to grow.

If you want to go for a DB solution only, I guess you will need to create a dedicated schema for your OLAP analysis or if using an external tool is ok for you, you can look around for OLAP tools. For example, [icCube](https://www.iccube.com/iccube-server/) allows for creating an OLAP schema that can be updated frequently to perform both daily and historical analysis.

Disclaimer: I work for icCube - I mentioned it as an example but other tools can do similar analysis.